# jquery selecting tags from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

can you select "html tags" that have been exported as text() ?

So if I have:

```
output = "<b>bold... lol</b>";
$('body').text(output);
```

Can I then easily select this `<b>` tag, or would I need something that looks for "&lt;b&gt;" or something? If so, how would I do that?

I guess I basically want to turn exported text() to html() for a few tags.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should also specify what you are trying to achieve at a higher level of abstraction. Like displaying text of posts that have code tags, etc. Or trying to implement a WYSIWYG editor in javascript... There may be another way to solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.innerHTML` for this.
Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/epuge4/4).

Comment: Thanks for this, but what if I have multiple tags on the page, like <i> and <u> but I only want <b> to actually become bold?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
output = $('<b>lol</b>');
$('body').append(output)
```

---

I guess, according to comments, that you have a text string

```
output = "<b>bold</b><i>notformatted</i>"
```

and you want to create tags from b's and keep everything else as is ?
If so I think you need to parse the string and create b-tags, concat rest of string and put the result in to the innerHTML.

Answer (score -1):

Change it to use html() rather than text()

```
output = "<b>bold... lol</b>";
$('body').html(output);
```

Then you should be able to access the tag using a normal selector

```
alert($('b').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/TECrk/

Comment: Your question isn't really very clear. You should clarify exactly what it is you want?